# Relative XPath queries iterating by 'level'

Tags: php, xpath, relative-path

I'm trying to figure out an XPath query string to perform the following operation.

Given an XML document like this:

```
<root>
    <data>foo1</data>
    <irrelevant-node>
        <data>foo1</data>
    </irrelevant-node>
    <irrelevant-node />
    <data>foo2</data>
    <irrelevant-node />
    <region>
        <data>bar1</data>
        <data>bar2</data>
        <irrelevant-node />
        <region>
            <data>hello1</data>
            <irrelevant-node />
            <data>hello2</data>
            <region>
                <irrelevant-node />
                <data>world1</data>
            </region>
        </region>
        <irrelevant-node />
        <data>bar3</data>
        <irrelevant-node>
            <data>foo1</data>
        </irrelevant-node>
        <irrelevant-node />
    </region>
    <irrelevant-node />
</root>
```

I want to grab all of the `<data>` nodes not contained within a `<region>`.

Then I want to grab all of the top-most `<region>` nodes and repeat the previous process on them, working relatively.

Essentially, I'm going to be performing a number of processes (PHP) on the `<data>` nodes based on their contents, then replacing them. However, `<region>` nodes act as a sort of scope delimiter, and once I finish processing all `<data>` nodes in a given scope, I move down a region-level. `<data>` nodes may be nested within other irrelevant nodes.

Not sure if XPath is the best tool for this, and I'm having alot of trouble trying to sort this out. As noted, I'm using the PHP implementation of the DOM classes.

Comment: the /root/region/irrelevant-node/data should be selected in the second iteration also with "bar..." `data`?

Comment: **@Alejandro**: That's correct. The first iteration should capture all the `foo` data. The second, `bar`. Third `hello`, and so forth.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Essentially, I'm going to be
>   performing a number of processes (PHP)
>   on the  nodes based on their
>   contents, then replacing them.
>   However,  nodes act as a sort
>   of scope delimiter, and once I finish
>   processing all `<data>` nodes in a given
>   scope, I move down a region-level.
>   `<data>` nodes may be nested within
>   other irrelevant nodes.

**Use**:

```
//data[count(ancestor::region) = $n]
```

where `$n` is 0, 1, ..., max-depth.

**For every value of $n the expression selects all `data` elements at "level $n"**.

**You can find the "max-depth"** as the maximum of the `count(ancestor::region)+1` for each of the nodes selected by:

```
//region[not(descendant::region)]
```

**This maximum *can* be specified in a single XPath 2.0 expression**, but not with a single XPath 1.0 expression.

Comment: Thank you **Dimitre Novatchev**; I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working; states that it is an invalid expression. I tested `//zuq:data[count(ancestor::zuq:region = 0)]` (I failed to mention the targeted nodes are in the `zuq` namespace) and it errored.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind, it was a collection of your and my typos :) Outstanding! Thanks again **Dimitre**!

Comment: @TomcatExodus: Sorry, I had to fix two typos in my answer. *Now* it is correct.